# With a batch script, how do I loop through a folder of pictures and move them to individual folders elsewhere?

Tags: loops, batch-file, xcopy

Long time reader, first time poster.

I've a folder of pictures...

```
c:\Users\user\Desktop\pictures
```

How do I cycle through the folder of pictures (names are timestamped so all names vary) and move them to specific folders?

The folder structure of the directory I'd like to move them to is like this...

```
c:\Users\user\Desktop\john\201209\
c:\Users\user\Desktop\james\201209\
c:\Users\user\Desktop\albert\201209\
c:\Users\user\Desktop\matt\201209\
etc
```

The pictures in the picture folder are taken alphabetically.

Right now, I can move all the pictures to another folder but can't get much further than that.

```
@echo off
:LOOP
echo File Copy Started 
xcopy /s /Y "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\" 
echo File Copy Completed
```

I assume I'll need a loop and in the loop maybe a case-like statement inside of it.  Maybe I won't need a case statement if everything is already in order.  I'm more of a PHP scripter than a batch scripter.

Comment: What format are the current filenames? How do we tell which pictures go in the John folder and which pictures go into the Albert folder?  Where is the date taken from?

Comment: The filename varies depending on which camera I use that month.  One is CIMG1111_tn.JPG for example while another is P1111111_tn.JPG and one is Image000011.jpg.

Comment: I was hoping that if I take the pictures in alphabetical order they're names will be in a alphanumeric order, and the folders are alphabetical as well.

Comment: and where are the time stamps?

Comment: Ok, but what criterion do we use to move the files to a set of folders?  Do you want all files starting with `c` moved to a folder called `Charles` for example?  You haven't made the task at all clear - edit your question please and provide further details.

Comment: I'm sorry, the pictures aren't necessarily timestamped as it's just numerically stamped.  
All of the pictures will be in one directory and are taken alphabetically. I'd like to move them to folders that are alphabetical.

Answer (score 0):

try these commands

copy 
source=...| destination=...|sort (not separate commands)

there is a program called [Drop-It](http://download.cnet.com/DropIt/3001-2248_4-75186238.html?spi=fa2e3a1b6b3b73cad16511001169abb7&dlm=0).
this program should perform a similar function to what you are trying to accomplish.
hope this helps